# calculate week number within a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How will I calculate week number within a date range ? Here my week starts from Saturday to Friday. And I have a start date and end date. With this, how will i calculate using SQL Query ?

Comment: I removed my answer - there were other logical issues with it I didn't catch.  Sorry!

Comment: Hope my updated answer helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DATEPART` to get the Week number,
and `DATEFIRST` to set the first day of the week. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx)

Example to get all week numbers in range with Saturday as the first day of week.

```
SET DATEFIRST 6
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DATEPART(WEEK, createDate) 
FROM 
    tblUser
WHERE
    createDate > '2005-01-01' AND createDate < '2011-01-01'
ORDER BY
    DATEPART(WEEK, createDate)
```

Comment: This will give the result, but my week starts from Saturday to Friday. The above query indicates for week starting from Sunday to Saturday, which is by default. So according to my week range, I should get current week number as 14, which I calculated manually

Answer (score 0):

You can use this and your SQL work operates well:

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english -- with your language 
GO
```